# What's the best (minimalist) way to cook venison, specifically the backstrap?

Tags: venison

A friend is trying to cook a recently butchered deer.   He was going to grill it, but was then advised that venison would do better with a slower cooking method.

The goal is a simple preparation - I'm not looking for recipe ideas, just the recommended way to cook deer backstrap to bring out its natural flavor.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut it into medallions or leave it whole. This is a very lean piece of meat. You can handle it as a steak and fry it in a skillet. However the middle should be (medium) rare, whatever your steak preference is. I would advice against a slow cooker method, but I haven't tried it.

After frying it in the skillet, use the sticky bits to make a wonderful sauce (with some red wine).

Answer (score 1):

Cut or slice back-strap into medallions.  Season with hot sauce, onion and garlic powder and a couple of beaten eggs.  Measurement of season dependent on taste/preferences and amount of meat.  Mix together seasoned fish fry, cornmeal or just plain flour.  If not using seasoned, then season to taste or diet requirements. Spray baking pan with non-stick or olive oil.  Drain deer meat from egg and coat with seasoned dry mix of choice. Lay on pan, top with pat of butter.  Cover and cook at 350 for 20 minute and check for doneness.  This of course is dependent on thickness of meat.  When no longer pick, uncover and let coating crisp.  This is a very forgiving recipe, but don't overcook without cover or will dry out.  We have tried all of the above seasoning and more.  We have tried all of the dry coating alone or all mixed together.  Good hunting!!  The back-strap is the tenderloin and the most prized piece of the deer to many.